# Unable to use module output in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have this tf that is referencing a modules instance role

```
resource "aws_kms_grant" "grant" {
  name              = "kms-grant"
  key_id            = module.cmk_module.key_id
  grantee_principal = module.elastic_beanstalk.arn
  operations        = ["Encrypt"]

}
```

The module being called by the grant:

```
module "elastic_beanstalk" {
  source         = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket.org/link-to-module"
  environment    = terraform.workspace
  component_name = "app-microservice"
  #Plus other config....
```

The modules outputs.tf

```
output "arn" {
  description = "Fixed iam instance role arn"
  value       = aws_iam_role.ec2.arn
}
```

When i run a plan on the tf that contains the grant, I get this error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

 on cmk.tf line 25, in resource "aws_kms_grant" “grant”:
 25:   grantee_principal = module.elastic_beanstalk.arn
   
 module.elastic_beanstalk is a object, known only after apply

 This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: What is the code in `elastic_beanstalk` module?

Comment: What that error is also saying is that the beanstalk resource does not yet exist so it cannot get the arn. I'm curious as to the overall structure... I would make the kms resource creation it's own module, then reference the beanstalk module and kms module in the same root module (where the terraform apply is run) & I too would like to see the elastic_beanstalk module & any other relevant terraform config to see if this issue can be re-created.

Comment: I don't see a reason why that would fail. Are you sure that the code you provided is the actual, real code that generates the error?

Comment: The statement "module.elastic_beanstalk is a object, known only after apply" here is just context to help understand the snippet shown above it. It's not part of the error, and so the unknown-ness of this value is not important here. It just means that `module.elastic_beanstalk.arn` would itself be unknown, if that attribute existed.